# Proving that Minimal Polynomial is Monic

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am given that $F \subseteq L$ and $L$ is an extension. Now, I am also given $T: L \to L$, $x \mapsto \alpha x$ and $m(x)\in F[x]$ to be the minimal polynomial of $T$ in $F$.

I have to demonstrate that $m$ is also the monic polynomial in $F[x]$ of minimal degree for which $m(\alpha)=0$, which means showing that $m$ is minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$.

Now, I think that we are usually familiar with showing and defining the minimal polynomial by what I said on the third sentence. This question is asking you to prove the converse, and I am not exactly sure how to even start this. Any tips as to how should I start? Help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: So, the minimal polinomial of $T$ in $L$ is $m(x)=x-\alpha$. Is $\alpha$ in $F$?

Comment: Since I was given that $\alpha \in L$, I would assume it would be since $L$ is the field extension?

Comment: Sorry, so I didn't get it. Since $T(x)=\alpha x$, we have that $x-\alpha$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$ in $L$. And if $x-\alpha$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ in $F$, then it means that $\alpha\in F$, which is not necessarily true.

Comment: I guess the exercise wants the minimal polynomial of $T$ in $F$, that is the minimal polynomial $m(x)\in F[x]$ such that $m(T)=0$.

Comment: I am given that $m \in F[x]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

(1) Verify that $\alpha$ is a root of $m(x)$.

Indeed, since $T=\alpha Id$, and $m(T)=0$,
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
m(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0 & \Rightarrow & 0=m(T)=a_n\alpha^nId+...+a_1\alpha Id+a_0Id
\\ & \Rightarrow & (a_n\alpha^n+...+a_1\alpha+a_0)Id = 0
\\ & \Rightarrow & m(\alpha) = a_n\alpha^n+...+a_1\alpha+a_0 = 0.
\end{array}
$$
(2) Since $\alpha$ is a root of $m(x)$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ in $F$, $m_\alpha(x)\in F[x]$, divides $m(x)$.

(3) But then, since $m(x)$ is irreducible, the fact that $m_\alpha(x)$ divides $m(x)$ implies that $m(x)=m_\alpha(x)$.

Comment: sorry, what is $\alpha Id$?

Comment: $\alpha Id$ is the multiplication of the scalar $\alpha$ with the linear operator identity $Id$.

Comment: It's another way of viewing $T$. The definition $T(x)=\alpha x$, means that $T=\alpha Id$.